# Why does this command work in the terminal but not in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, printf, ed

I have a command which runs successfully from the command line and turns this:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line
extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

into this:

```
1 first line
2 second line
3 third line
4 fourth line; extra bit
5 fifth line
6 sixth line
```

Here is the command:

```
printf "%s\n" '2,$g/^[^0-9]/-1s/$/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s file
```

It works when run from the command line. However, when I try to run the same thing from a makefile, `file` is not changed and I get this error message:

```
$ make
printf "%s\n" '2,/^[^0-9]/-1s/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s file
?
make: *** [make] Error 2
```

Here is the makefile, containing that same command:

```
make:
        printf "%s\n" '2,$g/^[^0-9]/-1s/$/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s file
```

How can I get this command to run with `make`?

Comment: In your makefile, try to put $$ where you have a single $.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html : _Because dollar signs are used to start make variable references, if you really want a dollar sign ... you must write two of them, ‘$$’_

Answer (score 1):

As @Philippe commented, the solution was to replace single dollar signs `$` with double dollar signs `$$`. Thus my makefile became:

```
make:
        printf "%s\n" '2,$$g/^[^0-9]/-1s/$$/; /\' '.,+1j' w | ed -s file
```

As explained in the [make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html), single dollar signs are expanded as 'variable and function references', so for a single dollar sign to be used as such it must be doubled.